# emacs list-buffers behavior

Tags: emacs, elisp

In GNU emacs, every time I hit <kbd>Ctrl-x Ctrl-b</kbd> to see all of my buffers, the window is split to show the buffer list, or if I have my window already split in 2 (for instance, I will have a shell running in the lower window), the buffer list appears in the other window.

My desired behavior is for the buffer list to appear in my active window so that I can select the buffer I want and continue to working in the same window, rather than having to <kbd>Ctrl-x Ctrl-o</kbd> to the other buffer, selecting the buffer (with <kbd>enter</kbd>) and editing that buffer in the other window... I've googled for it but it doesn't seem to be a common desire? I wonder if anyone has an elispy (or other) solution?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You might want to rebind <kbd>C-x C-b</kbd> to invoke `buffer-menu` rather than `list-buffers`:

```
(global-set-key "\C-x\C-b" 'buffer-menu)
```

Comment: I wanna know if there is way that you can use the short key such as 1, 2,... or a, b, c...to open one buffer more quickly, I know ac-jump-buffer could do that, but its buffer list is too simple, no extra information such as mode, size column in buffer-menu. If you solve this problem, that would be appreciated. @zimbu668

Answer (score 16):

Just customize the variable `same-window-regexps`.  `display-buffer` will display any buffer whose name matches a regexp there in the currently-selected window.

(You will want to add "`[*]Buffer List`".)

Comment: This is the best answer here, as it gets down to the real issue (modifying how display-buffer behaves), as opposed to providing workarounds.

Answer (score 14):

not exactly a solution, but `ido-mode` provides a different and powerful way to interact with buffers.  `C-x b` will then show a list of all the open buffers, and the one you select will open in the current window.

Comment: I wonder why you got downvoted... always good to know I have options!

Comment: In case you're checking back, thanks for the suggestion. I am a fan of ido now.

Answer (score 7):

Strangely, there isn't an answer here about `ibuffer`.

I would recommend this as a standard change for the majority of Emacs users:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-b") 'ibuffer)
```

ibuffer is a very advanced replacement for the default buffer listing, and not only features the exact behaviour requested, but provides a wealth of other functionality.

I listed a few ibuffer filtering and grouping basics in 
[Emacs: help me understand file/buffer management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145332/emacs-help-me-understand-file-buffer-management/3145824#3145824), but be sure to read the documentation for details.

Answer (score 5):

Try to add

```
(ido-mode 1)
```

to your .emacs, and enjoy the result :)

Answer (score 3):

If you like the original buffer list (as opposed to the `'buffer-menu` solution proposed by others), you can use this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-b") 'my-list-buffers)
(defun my-list-buffers (&optional files-only)
  "Display a list of names of existing buffers.
The list is displayed in a buffer named `*Buffer List*'.
Note that buffers with names starting with spaces are omitted.
Non-null optional arg FILES-ONLY means mention only file buffers.

For more information, see the function `buffer-menu'."
  (interactive "P")
  (switch-to-buffer (list-buffers-noselect files-only)))
```

Which is the same function as before, only in the current window.

Comment: I am using a variant now with switch-to-buffer-other-window and special behaviour if I am already in Buffer list. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend bs.el from http://www.geekware.de/software/emacs/  Install it and:

```
(require 'bs)
(add-hook 'bs-mode-hook 'turn-on-font-lock)
(global-set-key "\C-x\C-b" 'bs-show)
```

It manages buffers and window configuration in the right way, so everything requires minimum number of keystrokes.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where I got this but:

```
;;; Faster buffer switching
(global-set-key [(C tab)] 'buffer-menu)
```

This makes Ctrl-Tab display all buffers in the current window.  You can then navigate to a buffer and hit Enter to visit it.

Comment: Thanks - I have Ctrl-tab already reserved though :). But buffer-menu is key.

Answer (score 0):

Another not-what-you-asked-for solution: don't select the desired buffer with the mouse, rather finish typing its name (use tab-completion to reduce keystrokes and increase accuracy), then hit return. The buffer list will disappear, and the new file will be open in the previously active window.

Comment: Thanks - but I mostly work in the terminal so no mouse there... but sometimes I get confused whether some buffers begin with * or not, but you're right, tab completions will even help me out there.

Comment: This does not remove the buffer list window for me ?