# how to stop Emacs from opening new buffers when following a link in customization

Tags: emacs, buffer, customization

The problem occurs when customizing options in Emacs. Every time I click on a link a new buffer is created. How to force Emacs to use single buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(defadvice custom-buffer-create (before my-advice-custom-buffer-create)
  "Exit the current Customize buffer before creating a new one, unless there are modified widgets."
  (if (eq major-mode 'Custom-mode)
      (let ((custom-buffer-done-kill t)
            (custom-buffer-modified nil))
        (mapc (lambda (widget)
                (and (not custom-buffer-modified)
                     (eq (widget-get widget :custom-state) 'modified)
                     (setq custom-buffer-modified t)))
              custom-options)
        (if (not custom-buffer-modified)
            (Custom-buffer-done)))))
(ad-activate 'custom-buffer-create)
```

Comment: edit: changed advice from `customize-group` to `custom-buffer-create`.

Comment: Please take note that if you have not yet saved a change in your current Customize buffer, you will lose those edits when you change to a new buffer.

Comment: Resolved the issue from the previous comment. Improvements to the code welcomed.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you. As to ibuffer I don't find the need for it now as I'm emacs noobie. Maybe in the future. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to my original answer (which I am not inclined to use myself), I thought I might suggest other ways in which you might deal with getting rid of lots of Customize buffers once you have finished customising things.

First, do note that simply pressing `q` will "Exit current Custom buffer according to `custom-buffer-done-kill'" (i.e. either bury it or kill it).

Second is to use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `kill-matching-buffers` <kbd>RET</kbd> `\*Customize` <kbd>RET</kbd> (and then confirm each one), but that's a bit tedious.

What I'd actually do is use [ibuffer](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IbufferMode).

If you don't use it already, I recommend binding <kbd>C-x C-b</kbd> to `ibuffer`, which is a greatly enhanced alternative to the default `list-buffers`. I love it primarily for its [filtering and grouping abilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145332/emacs-help-me-understand-file-buffer-management/3145824#3145824), but it can do a great deal besides that.

```
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-b") 'ibuffer)
```

I also use the advice which can currently be found [here at the Emacs Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IbufferMode#toc10) so that ibuffer always opens with the buffer I came from selected.

That done, and from a Customize buffer, <kbd>C-x C-b * M RET D y</kbd> will kill all the Customize buffers. That is:

- <kbd>C-x C-b</kbd> Open ibuffer (with point on the current Customize buffer entry)
- <kbd>* M</kbd> Mark buffers by major mode...
- <kbd>RET</kbd> ...select the mode (which defaulted to the major mode of the selected buffer, or otherwise type `Custom-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>)
- <kbd>D y</kbd> kill all marked buffers

Try it out; you'll probably like it. [Searching for ibuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ibuffer) will turn up other handy uses.

For instance, you could use `/ n ^\* RET / g tmp RET` to separate out all buffers starting with `*` into a "tmp" group, so that they don't clutter up the group of buffers you are more likely to be interested in.

As with any major mode, use <kbd>C-h m</kbd> to read the built-in documentation.