# Emacs Lisp Buffer out of focus function?

Tags: emacs, buffer, elisp

Is there an emacs lisp function that will allow me to tell if a buffer is out of focus?

I am trying to write a hook that will get rid of the semantics `*possible completion's*` buffer right after it is out of focus.

Also is it possible to get rid of the `*Messages*` Buffer as well? I haven't found a function that would kill it.

Comment: As ataylor indicated, killing `*Messages*` isn't a good idea. How is it causing you problems?

Comment: I just want to reduce the clutter in the buffers list i find it annoying when a few things happen, when I do a dired it doesn't close the buffer as I finish with it, when I do a completion it leaves that buffer open as soon as its done, when I am in a current frame and want to switch buffers more buffers to run through are required

Comment: Consider adding a global key binding for `M-x bury-buffer`. Be aware that `q` buries the buffer in many major modes (dired, help, info, customize, etc, etc...). Rebind `C-x C-b` to `ibuffer` instead of the default `list-buffers`, and then learn how you can filter and group the listing to keep unwanted buffers out of the way. For dired you can use `a` to remove the dired buffer when opening files or directories. (edit: in fact, I have a previous answer which goes into more detail on exactly these suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3145824/324105 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related to your second question, *Also is it possible to get rid of the Messages Buffer as well*. If you're using `ido-mode` (and everyone should be using it!), you can hide the `*Messages*` buffer from the buffer listing with the following elisp:

```
(require 'ido)
(setq ido-ignore-buffers '("^\*Messages\*"))
```

Comment: "and everyone should be using it"
  
Ido is better than the default completion mechanism.  But Anything is far ans away better than ido when you have to select amongst a big list long strings (i.e. buffer names).

Comment: I tried using Anything a while back, and found it too weird / intrusive / in your face IIRC. I'm a heavy QuickSilver user on OS X, so maybe I should give Anything another try...

Comment: "^\*Messages\*" do we have to use the regex in this case ?

Answer (score 2):

You can test if a buffer is the buffer that currently has focus with `current-buffer`.  For example, to test if `*scratch*` has the focus,

```
(eq 
 (current-buffer) 
 (get-buffer "*scratch*"))
```

The `*Messages*` buffer is an important part of emacs.  It's the implicit target of the `message` function that is used to log various bits of information from all over.  You can kill `*Messages*` like any other buffer, but it will just get recreated the next time something calls `message`.  You could probably silence it by redefining the `message` function, but I'd question the point of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [PopWin](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PopWin), It lets you specify buffers that will open in a special window. This window closes when the frame gets out of focus or when you press C-g