# Emacs disable *Messages* buffer

Tags: emacs

Is there a way to disable the *Messages* buffer? I know I can kill it, but it reappears. I know I can scroll through buffers without passing by *Messages*, but is there a way I can just disable the creation of it?

Thank you.

Comment: How do you switch buffers? I hope you don't use the horribly inefficient default buffer switching. Check out [iswitchb](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/IswitchBuffers) and then you can go directly to any buffer, so you don't have to pass by *Messages*. The Messages buffer is useful, by the way, you'll learn to appreciate it, for example, when you print out informative messages from elisp.

Comment: Don't disable `*Messages*`; it's a bad idea. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536186/emacs-lisp-buffer-out-of-focus-function for some suggestions of ways to stop it (and other such buffers) from getting in your way.

Comment: @Tom, isn't `*Messages*` getting matched when you switch with iswitchb too, adding to the ambiguity of a substring?

Comment: @katspaugg you can filter out Messages if you want to with the variable iswitchb-buffer-ignore

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can customize the variable `message-log-max` and give a value of `nil` to disable logging:

```
Maximum number of lines to keep in the message log buffer.
If nil, disable message logging.  If t, log messages but don't truncate
the buffer when it becomes large.
```

I tried killing the `*Messages*` buffer, producing messages (that show on the minibuffer), and no new messages buffer appears.

Comment: thank for the tip. It's been bugging me for a very log time now. bw.

Comment: answer underneath actually provides the code to add to `.emacs` which achieves this

Answer (score 26):

Based on the answer above, place this in your .emacs to completely disable the *messages*

```
;; Forces the messages to 0, and kills the *Messages* buffer - thus disabling it on startup.
(setq-default message-log-max nil)
(kill-buffer "*Messages*")
```

Also, if you're like me, this is how you remove the *Completions* buffer that appears when opening a new file from the buffer.

```
;; Disabled *Completions*
(add-hook 'minibuffer-exit-hook 
      '(lambda ()
         (let ((buffer "*Completions*"))
           (and (get-buffer buffer)
            (kill-buffer buffer)))))
```

Comment: See also [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152151/72170) if you feel like removing scratch, messages and completions altogether.

Comment: Could I do it also for `*scratch` ? @Ole

Comment: Check out the link in the comment above, @alper