# Emacs creates too many buffers

Tags: emacs

Emacs creates far too many buffers, like this one when it starts up:

```
Loading /home/david/.recentf...done
Cleaning up the recentf list...done (0 removed)
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
```

And others like the following one when I want auto-completes:

```
Click <mouse-2> on a completion to select it.
In this buffer, type RET to select the completion near point.

Possible completions are:
perl-backward-to-noncomment     perl-beginning-of-function
perl-electric-terminator    perl-end-of-function
perl-indent-command     perl-indent-exp
perl-mark-function  perl-mode
perldb
```

Is there a way I can just make emacs kill auto-completion buffers and not create that one on the beginning? Thanks.

Comment: I think they are useful sometimes, but why you want to forbid them Since they don't come generally come in your way.?

Comment: You accept too few answers.

Comment: See harpo's answer. You shouldn't travel the buffer list in a linear order when you want to switch to a buffer. It's very inefficient. Just use [iswitchb](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IswitchBuffers) and you won't have to worry about how many open buffers you have.

Comment: When I was first learning emacs I had a lot of trouble with buffers, so I asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145332/emacs-help-me-understand-file-buffer-management. A lot of the suggestions there helped me out, particularly ido-mode: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or just disable the scratch, message and completions buffer altogether, without breaking anything:

Posted first [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152151/72170), and pasted bellow:

Place this in your .emacs:

```
;; Makes *scratch* empty.
(setq initial-scratch-message "")

;; Removes *scratch* from buffer after the mode has been set.
(defun remove-scratch-buffer ()
  (if (get-buffer "*scratch*")
      (kill-buffer "*scratch*")))
(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook 'remove-scratch-buffer)

;; Removes *messages* from the buffer.
(setq-default message-log-max nil)
(kill-buffer "*Messages*")

;; Removes *Completions* from buffer after you've opened a file.
(add-hook 'minibuffer-exit-hook
      '(lambda ()
         (let ((buffer "*Completions*"))
           (and (get-buffer buffer)
                (kill-buffer buffer)))))

;; Don't show *Buffer list* when opening multiple files at the same time.
(setq inhibit-startup-buffer-menu t)

;; Show only one active window when opening multiple files at the same time.
(add-hook 'window-setup-hook 'delete-other-windows)
```

Bonus:

```
;; No more typing the whole yes or no. Just y or n will do.
(fset 'yes-or-no-p 'y-or-n-p)
```

Answer (score 5):

I felt this way when I first started using emacs.  While I do generally close such "temporary" buffers when I'm done with them, the more general answer is that you just need to put them out of your mind and develop a workflow where you can get to the buffers you *do* want.  Otherwise, you're going to start regarding your *own* buffers as clutter when they are not relevant, and waste energy closing them.

`iswitchb-mode` is a good start.

Answer (score 4):

in emacs 24 there is the elisp function:

clean-buffer-list

this is provided by [MidnightMode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MidnightMode) which can be added to other versions.

As the name suggests that can also be scheduled.

Answer (score 2):

A alternative to iswitchb mode is `ido-mode` which is very similar but looks a little cleaner, it also makes `C-x-C-f` (find file) look nicer.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, if you choose iswitchb you also can setup it to ignore certain buffers. Just add the following code to your emacs init file:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'iswitchb-buffer-ignore "*Messages*")
(add-to-list 'iswitchb-buffer-ignore "*scratch")
(add-to-list 'iswitchb-buffer-ignore "*Completions")
```

Comment: Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/david/.emacs.el':

Symbol's value as variable is void: iswitchb-buffer-ignore

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.

I got that when I added those three lines to the config file, thank you!

Comment: That's maybe because you didn't install iswitchb. So you must install it first. In order to do that, you should add (iswitchb-mode 1) before the others. I.e.: 

    `(iswitchb-mode 1)
    (add-to-list 'iswitchb-buffer-ignore "*Messages*")
    (add-to-list 'iswitchb-buffer-ignore "*scratch")
    (add-to-list 'iswitchb-buffer-ignore "*Completions")`
I'm sure that help.

Comment: I added that, but I still get the starting buffer "Loading /home/david/.recentf...done (...)"