# Emacs Buffer Management

Tags: emacs

I was wondering how people manage with the useless messages etc emacs buffers generated randomly, for example after my completions, I get an completions buffer and it upsets me it create a buffer I have to traverse to get to the next buffer. Anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emacs: help me understand file/buffer management](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145332/emacs-help-me-understand-file-buffer-management)

Comment: Doesn't it get closed and buried after use? It should not come in the way of cycling through buffers, since it is a special (starts with a *) buffer.

Answer (score 4):

The title is rather vague. There are lots of Q&As on the general subject of "buffer management" in Emacs. Here's one which includes links to several others (see "Linked" in the right-hand sidebar):
[How can I more easily switch between buffers in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394289/how-can-i-more-easily-switch-between-buffers-in-emacs)

For your specific question, I suggest using the excellent `winner-mode`. Just add `(winner-mode 1)` to your .emacs file (or type <kbd>M-x</kbd> `winner-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd> to try it out).

Once enabled, you can call `winner-undo` with <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd><left></kbd> (repeatedly, if necessary) to step backwards through all the previous window configurations.

Thus, when a window pops up and you no longer want it, you type <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd><left></kbd> and you're immediately back to how things were before.

<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd><right></kbd> calls `winner-redo` which restores the configuration you started with (i.e. it doesn't step through the configurations like the undo command).

Also note that many types of buffer can be buried with <kbd>q</kbd> or deleted with <kbd>z</kbd>.