# Emacs 25 and list-buffers behavior

Tags: emacs, emacs25

Can someone help me make sense of list-buffer (aka <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>) behavior in emacs 25?

The [behavior I'm used to seeing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231188/emacs-list-buffers-behavior) is that it opens the buffer list in another Emacs window (virtual Emacs window), splitting out a second window to do so, if necessary. In some versions it hasn't always been very deterministic which other window it used (if I had more than 2 up), but I could at least count on it not using the one the cursor was in.

I recently installed 25.0.50.1 to get around a remote file open bug (worked!), and now it isn't always doing this. Very often it opens the buffer list in the same window my cursor was in. Often it works the way it used to. I can't figure out any rhyme or reason behind which it choses to do.

Can someone enlighten me as to the algorithm it is using now? It makes managing multiple emacs Windows for reference viewing nearly impossible when I can't predict which window gets replaced.

Comment: After you get your answer, if you feel the doc or behavior is not clear or what you would prefer, consider filing a bug/enhancement request: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: If you are interested in making it work the way you want by creating your own function, there are a few threads [available by Googling] that discuss how to make it display left/right/above/below.  However, most people seem to prefer advice'ing or display-buffer-alist'ing to workaround the default behavior of existing functions instead of simply creating new ones -- there are probably some threads for those methods also, but I haven't checked.

Comment: @lawlist - Before I decide on changing the default behavior, I'd like to know exactly what the default behavior currently is.

Comment: The question is really about ascertaining the default behavior of the function `display-buffer`.  I suggest that you read the doc-string of that function, which can be viewed by typing:  `M-x describe-function RET display-buffer RET`.  The function `list-buffers` is one (1) line of code excluding the doc-string and interactive statement -- i.e., `(display-buffer (list-buffers-noselect arg))`.  Noselect is self-explanitory -- i.e.., a buffer is generated containing the ingredients you are accustomed to seeing, and then it just sits there waiting to be displayed -- e.g., by `display-buffer`.

Comment: @lawlist - Either that doc-string of display-buffer explains nothing about how list-buffer choses the buffer window to use, or it is doing it in a way far beyond my meer mortal perception.

Comment: The doc of `display-buffer` and `display-buffer-alist`, as well as the behavior they try to describe and explain, is indeed "**way far beyond my meer [sic] mortal perception** (and understanding). FWIW, I'm with you on that one - I've never been able to fathom it either.

Answer (score 5):

I would guess your primary concern is to have a convenient way to switch buffer, not to understand the emacs' source code, so I would strongly recommend to check `helm` package out: http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html
It will take about 10 to 20 minutes to install and follow the tutorial, and it is well worth. I promise.

After installing `helm` and enabling it, the key sequence for you is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd>: `Shows open buffers, recently opened files`

You will get a power pack of many other tools to work in emacs. I had the same problem with switching buffers, and seemingly 'chaotic' buffer popup. After `helm` installation, the problem is minimized to invisible because it is so easy to switch to the buffers you want.

**Update**:

To deal package installation errors and package compatibility:
`M-x list-load-path-shadows` to see if there is any conflicting packages. And since you may not have many external packages, I suggest backup `~/.emacs.d` and have a new empty one. Also, most of the case when install packages, I try to use emacs package manager. Benefits of using package manger:

- help check dependencies
- avoid to manual download and unpack.
- can do batch update of installed packages

Following is a workflow of enabling `melpa` repo and installing packages

```
M-x customize-group RET package
# Click or move cursor to and enter: Package Archives
# Insert the melpa repository. 
Archive name: melpa
URL or directory name: http://stable.melpa.org/packages/
#Save above settings and then you can use the following to install packages:
M-x list-packages RET
f to filer package names
i to mark for installation
x for execution of installation
u for unmark package at cursor. 

# to avoid using load-path repeatedly,
# I have this in my .emacs before any 'require' command:
; Set path recursively to one folder
(let ((default-directory "~/.emacs.d/elpa/"))(normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path))
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll check it out. I generally don't like adding external packages to my emacs except for specific short-term needs. Emacs has a nasty habit of evolving out from under them, and then I end up with the joyous task of trying to figure out what arcane .emacs entries I have to modify/delete to get things working again, years after I've forgotten why they were in there and what they do. There are exceptions though.

Comment: To cope with this, I actually comment my `.emacs` file a lot, on every modification I make. However, sometimes it may happen that your favorite key seqeunces get redefined, or packages get shadowed. These key sequences may be very helpful: `C-h m`: List loaded modes. `C-h k`: key sequence explained. `M-x list-load-path-shadows`: find out conflicting paths. Or even simply `C-s` to search for duplicated key sequences in `.emacs`.

Comment: I went and looked at it. For my purposes, kinda seems like using a hammer to swat a fly. I did like the looks of the Everything search it uses on Windows though. So I tried to install it. No dice. I get an error when I try to require it in my .emacs. A web search tells me its probably due to reuse of a name another package is using, but "everything" isn't exactly an uncommon word in .el files, so I have no clue which it is in the sea of hits. Did I mention earlier why I don't like adding external packages to my emacs?

Comment: That's what I meant by 'power pack'. I have updated the post to help with installation and package conflict. Besides, Emacs 25 is still in beta stage, so instability should be expected. Therefore it is a good idea to have a fresh setup.